# What's the Noda Time 2.0 equivalent of MapTimeZoneId?

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have been using the following code without flaw for a while now:

```
internal static string WindowsToIana(string windowsZoneId)
{
    if (windowsZoneId.Equals("UTC", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        return "Etc/UTC";

    var tzdbSource = NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;
    var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(windowsZoneId);
    if (tzi == null) return null;
    var tzid = tzdbSource.MapTimeZoneId(tzi);
    if (tzid == null) return null;
    return tzdbSource.CanonicalIdMap[tzid];
}
```

When upgrading NodaTime to version 2.0, I now get a compile-time error saying `MapTimeZoneId` no longer exists. How do I get this function working again?

Comment: Major version is incremented with a reason. Check the documentation for the new version and learn how to use the new types.

Comment: @zerkms - I did that by looking [here](http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/migration-to-2). It makes no mention of this method at all.

Comment: http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html --- there is no such method in the v2.

Comment: @zerkms - Correct. I knew that method was removed. What I am asking is how to get the same functionality as before. E.g., what is the alternative method?

Comment: Have you checked the new documentation first?

Comment: I checked the link I posted in my comment up above, about how to migrate from NodaTime 1.x to 2.x.

Comment: Good. But not sure why you did not read the documentation or the source code. It took 15 seconds for me to find the https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/commit/3599643da4f53988c95b272a23f7fe7aa5682cb5

Comment: `NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull(theZone)`

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/811 for the lack of documentation in the migration guide. If you're just trying to convert the string, you might want to use Matt Johnson's TimeZoneConverter project: https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter

Comment: If you want Noda Time for other reasons, and you want to use the same data, you'd need to go through the Windows Zone mappings in the TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.

Comment: @Gusman: No, `GetZoneOrNull` takes a provider-oriented ID. This is about mapping...

Comment: I've edited the question to be more specific: the original title is alarmist if you don't know it's a major version update, and pointless if you know it *is* a major version update.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, you need the same code that exists within the gut of Noda Time, but it's not very much:

```
internal static string WindowsToIana(string windowsZoneId)
{
    // Avoid UTC being mapped to Etc/GMT, which is the mapping in CLDR
    if (windowsZoneId == "UTC")
    {
        return "Etc/UTC";
    }
    var source = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;
    string result;
    // If there's no such mapping, result will be null.
    source.WindowsMapping.PrimaryMapping.TryGetValue(windowsZoneId, out result);
    // Canonicalize
    if (result != null)
    {
        result = source.CanonicalIdMap[result];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notes:

- This code will work with time zone IDs that aren't present on your system for whatever reason, but are present in CLDR
- If this is *all* you're doing with Noda Time, consider using [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) instead
- If you run on .NET Core on non-Windows systems, `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` will probably already be an IANA ID, so this code would return `null` in most cases.

I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/811) to handle the fact that this isn't mentioned in the migration guide.